# Google Maps API Example not working, giving me blank screen

Tags: html, css, google-maps, google-chrome

The Google Maps API tutorial (https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/fundamentals/adding-a-google-map) is giving me a blank screen. I have been working on this for 3 hours and cannot figure it out.

I even copied/pasted the code exactly, it is saved as an .html file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #map_canvas{
        height: 500px;
        width: 400px;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
      function initialize() {
        var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
        var map_options = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.5403, -78.5463),
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options)
      }
       google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, ‘load’, initialize);
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have illegal characters in your code:

```
Timestamp: 08/12/2013 02:08:39 PM
Error: illegal character
Line: 21, Column: 48
Source Code:
   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, $(B!F(Bload$(B!G(B, initialize);
```

Change:

```
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, ‘load’, initialize);
```

To:

```
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `&callback=initialize` to your URL, that extra parameter tells Google that this is the function to call. That function must be accessible from the `window` scope.