# Embedded google maps doesn't show in HTML page

Tags: html, google-maps, google-api

I'm playing around with google map apis following the google maps tutorial https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/fundamentals/adding-a-google-map
but with the following code the map doesn't show in my html code example.

Any suggestions?

Regards

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #map_canvas {
      width: 500px;
      height: 400px;
                  }
    </style>
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
        function initialize() {
        var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
        var map_options = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.5403, -78.5463),
        zoom: 8,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                          }   
        var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options)
                              }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, ‘load’, initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps API Example not working, giving me blank screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18196229/google-maps-api-example-not-working-giving-me-blank-screen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, ‘load’, initialize);
```

Contains invalid characters.  This should work:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: Perfect it's working now!
Its seems quite strange to me that a google tutorial contains an error, how is that possible?

Comment: probably due to the way it was copied/pasted out of the documentation.